# What language is more suitable for quantum machine learning algorithms?

Tags: programming, resource-request, machine-learning

What language is more suitable for quantum machine learning algorithms? Is it right that it's Python + Pyquil? Or something else?

And do you know the sources where you can see the sample codes of different quantum ML algorithms if it exists? I didn't find anything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One can recommend [PennyLane](https://pennylane.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) by Xanadu.AI. You can find complete examples of quantum machine learning algorithms (e.g. Iris Classification), using hybrid quantum-classical computations.

Additionally, they offer built-in [plugins](https://pennylane.ai/plugins.html) for IBM QisKit, Pyquil etc., to enable running Pennylane QML codes on IBM and Rigetti quantum hardwares.

Comment: if Pennylane can incorporate IBM's Qiskit and Rigetti's Pyquil, will definitely look into it